# Savvy way of deleting empty rows in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there any better way than looping through an array to check for an empty row and deleting those? I have an array of strings, I want to delete those rows which have no strings, the only way I can think of is looping through.

Eg

```
a = np.array([[''],
             ['string1'],
             ['string2'],
             ['']]))
```

How do I get only string1 and string 2 as the entries?

Comment: What do you mean with "an array of strings in numpy"?

Comment: A list of string lists converted to a numpy array, i.e. : [['hello']['']['bye']] - I would like to remove wherever there is an empty string inside.

Comment: Assuming that you just forgot the commas, you are talking about a list of 1-element lists of strings. You can still use logical indexing: `a[a!=['']]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an array

```
a = np.array(['foo', '', 'bar', '', '', 'baf'])
```

you could use logical indexing

```
a[a!=''] # -> array(['foo', 'bar', 'baf'], dtype='<U3')
```

If you have a 2D numpy array of strings

```
b = np.array([[''],
             ['string1'],
             ['string2'],
             ['']])
```

and want to get rid of lines containing only an empty string, you can go

```
b[b!=['']] # -> array(['string1', 'string2'], dtype='<U7')
```